# Drupal image galley for every blog post and social links

Tags: drupal

I am working on Drupal 7 and my client wants to have image gallery in blog they post. Is there a simple module which does that. I have tried many modules but none worked as the way i wanted it to be.

Also i want a another module which enables registered user to have their own social links, for eg  facebook and twitter. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is almost always a module for that - https://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter will let you create a content field that is an image gallery. It looks like it is pretty flexible.

To allow users to have social media links in their profile checkout https://drupal.org/project/follow.